# How to compare two elements of list

Tags: coq

I have a list with all elements equal to zero and the length of the list not equal to zero. I want to prove the following and compare both

```
 (length l=?0)=false->
  k < length l ->
 (forall k, nth k l 0 = 0)->
 1<=count 0 l.

(length l=?0)=false->
(forall k, nth k l 0 = 0) ->
(S n) <  length l ->
count  (S n) l = 0.

count  (S n) l < count 0 l.

 Fixpoint count (v:nat) (s:list nat) : nat :=
 match s with
| [] => 0 
| h :: t => (if beq_nat h v then 1 else 0) + (count v t) end.
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the problem? We don't even know what your definition of `count` is. Also instead of proving anything `<= 0` you should consider proving it equal to `0` instead.

Comment: You should have parenthesis like this around `(forall k, nth k l 0 = 0) ->` otherwise you are only saying that for _one particular_ k `nth k l 0` is zero, not that it is zero for all k.  Since you are using zero as default, that k may not even index into the list, so the list may just contain non-zero elements, according to your formulation.

Comment: I have updated the question.Use parenthesis,k<length l so that we can talk about elements  of list.(all elements are zero). Define count  & Instead of <= 0  use =0 as said  @ Theo Winterhalter